# 2 Forms (select) - 1 is dependent from 2

Tags: php, forms

I want create form in `html`+`php`. I have got 2 tables in my database.

1. **Categories:** id_category, category
2. **Dairy:** id_dairy, id_category, product_name

And now is question. How can I create 1 form with 2 `select` dropdowns. Is it possible to do it in PHP without AJAX?

I mean that - I want choose Category and then choose Products without refresh page.

Code:

```
<form role="form" action="kalorie.php" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="kategoria">Kategoria:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="kategoria">
          <option>Wybierz kategorie</option>
            <?php
              $sql_1 = "SELECT * FROM produkty";
              $result_1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_1);

              while($row_1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_1)) {
                echo '<option>'.$row_1["produkt"].'</option>';
              }

              $kat = $_POST['kategoria'];
            ?>
        </select>
        <select class="form-control" name="produkt">
          <option>Wybierz produkt</option>
            <?php
              $sql_2 = "SELECT * FROM $kat";
              $result_2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_2);

              while($row_2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_2)) {
                echo '<option>'.$row_2["produkty"].'</option>';
              }
            ?>
        </select>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="oblicz">Wyślij</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: If you don't want to refresh the page you need to do it with AJAX.It's the unique way possible to send/get data from server without refresh the page.

Comment: You would at least need Javascript/jQuery for this.

Comment: +1 what has already been said above.  The only way without ajax is it use an onchange or onselect event, but that will refresh the page and pre-populate the next select list..

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is best solution for this.
But if you want an alternative than you can use "iframe" and submit ypur form in that frame.

Answer (score 0):

Non Ajax solution:

Load your product subcategories into a JavaScript object keyed by the category id. When the category is changed in the category select list, swap out the options in the product list.

```
<script>
var produkts = {
<?php
$sql_2 = "SELECT * FROM $kat";
$result_2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_2);

$id_category = 0;
list($delim1, $delim2) = array('', '');
while($row_2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_2)) {
    $delim2 = '"';
    $row_2 = $row['value'];
    if ( $id_category != $row_2['id_category'] ) {
        $id_category = $row_2['id_category'];
        echo $delim1 . $id_category . ': "';
        $delim1 = '", ';
    }
    echo '<option>' . $row_2['produkty'] . '</option>';
}
echo $delim2;

?>
};
// example: {1: "<option>cheese</option><option>butter</option>", 2: "<option>ice cream</option>"}
</script>

<form role="form" action="kalorie.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="kategoria">Kategoria:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="kategoria">
      <option>Wybierz kategorie</option>
        <option value="1">Me</option>
        <option value="2">You</option>
        <?php
          $sql_1 = "SELECT * FROM produkty";
          $result_1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_1);

          while($row_1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_1)) {
            echo '<option>'.$row_1["produkt"].'</option>';
          }

          $kat = $_POST['kategoria'];
        ?>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control" name="produkt">
      <option>Wybierz produkt</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="oblicz">Wyślij</button>
</form>

<script>

document.querySelector('select[name=kategoria]').addEventListener('change', function (evt) {
    var kat = evt.target;
    var kat_sel = kat.options[kat.selectedIndex].value
    document.querySelector('select[name=produkt]').innerHTML = produkts[kat_sel];
})

</script>
```

[Mocked up JSFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/acufg6bz/)